# Form firing javascript onsubmit but not passing values from form POST

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the form action POST to submit a form and javascript onsubmit to redirect a user to the thank you page. The POST was working prior to adding the javascript code, and once that was implemented the form is redirecting correctly but not calling up the POST page to process the values anymore.

```
<form action="https://www.website.com/leads.php" method="post" id="bm-form" class="form-style" novalidate="novalidate">
    <!--form fields here-->
<div>
    <input class="btn theme-btn" value="Process" type="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("bm-form").onsubmit=function() {
    window.location.replace("https://www.website.com/thank-you.html");
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to keep the client on the page while submitting form data then I suggest you take a look at using ajax. Once the ajax is complete you can check/confirm the post is a success and then redirect the user to another page or display a thank you message. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: This was the solution I used, thank you very much! If you add this in the answers then I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript is cancelling the normal behaviour of the form submission and telling the browser to load a different page instead.

To redirect to a thank-you page, have `https://www.website.com/leads.php` return a `302` status and a `Location` HTTP response header. Don't involve JavaScript.

Comment: Is it possible to do it all from the index page listed above? That page is used to process other leads and is not subject to change (not my decision but have to follow it).

Answer (score 0):

You should do the redirect from inside the php code (leads.php) server side not from javascript. The javascript logic you have added it overwrites the form submit and post is never done, just the redirect is.